# Running ansible_pull from systemd: git/ssh credentials?

Tags: ssh, git, ansible

I currently have a home server (old laptop) I'm provisioning with Ansible in
the classical push fashion, by pushing from my personal computer to it.
This works, but requires me to push after every restart.

I want to change this to a pull configuration, where the server has a systemd
timer/service pair that runs Ansible pull from git every 5 minutes and applies
the changes if there are some, and also unconditionally pulls on boot.

The repo I'm trying to pull from is private and needs git credentials or SSH key.
**If I run Ansible from systemd in non-user mode, how can I set an ssh key for Ansible (or user/password for https auth) to
use when pulling from Git?**

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `ansible-pull` has an arg for that which I just didn't see in the docs:

`--private-key <PRIVATE_KEY_FILE>, --key-file <PRIVATE_KEY_FILE>`
use this file to authenticate the connection

(from [`ansible-pull` documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-pull.html))

Thanks to Xaroth on #ansible on irc.libera.chat!

Answer (score 0):

parameters appear to be described here: https://gist.github.com/turboBasic/d6c6ffcb5d184b0c255b1054833b3c0f

I have no idea why such a commonly fielded request is not described with an example in the documentation. Number of user-hours wasted...

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo ansible-pull --url ssh://git@github.com/you/your-ansible-repo.git \
        --key-file ~/.ssh/id_rsa --accept-host-key \
        --checkout develop \
        packages.yml
```